# Should I use ChangeDetectionStrategy OnPush with Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Should someone use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` with Ionic 3?

I am used to turning it on in every Angular app. but with Ionic, most of the components stop working properly when `OnPush` is on, like the tabs and the refresher, then I have to do some hacks and detect the changes manually to get it to work properly.

Is it a good practice to have it on in Ionic? or it is not necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I think the way your question is phrased right now is a bit odd (Cause answer will be: **"of course use it, but learn how it works and what it does and know when it is worth to do it"**).

Ionic 3 leverages Angular under the hood and change detection is Angular's "feature". To use it in advanced manner or not with Ionic 3 (same as with Angular) is mostly the question of particular application context: like for example if you have a large project with tons of data bindings in a lot of components and there is performance concern => you should definitely consider change detection strategy as part of your optimization.

Indeed some of the components that Ionic team built might need additional attention and they may not "respect" CD out of box (in many cases it is because they use mutable values etc and you have to add check logic into ngDoCheck hook yourself etc), but you can always check the sources and figure out the reason CD is not working as you expect. And there is tangible value of doing CD.onPush in your own components if your app is very performance demanding.

So in summary:

- understanding of change detection, how it works and when it helps is pretty critical for serious angular development in general.
- definitely it should be considered for apps that have/will have a lot of components/bindings to help optimize performance at due time. It makes sense to write such apps from the start with future CD optimization in mind.